# Django 1.10 NoReverseMatch - exits but does not match?

Tags: django, image, templates, url, match

I wanted to build a 'list' view where all the images in the database will be displayed.
This is the template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Your images{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for picture in images %}

            <a href="{% url "detail" id=picture.id slug=picture.slug %}">
            <img src="{{ picture.image.url }}" class="image-detail">
            </a>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

And the list and detail urls :

`url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w]+)/$',views.image_detail,name='detail')`

`url(r'^list/$', views.image_list, name='list')`

When the user clicks a picture, he should be redirected to that page 'detail' view .

```
def image_detail(request, id, slug):
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, id=id, slug=slug)
    return render(request,
    'images/image/detail.html',
    {'section': 'images',
    'image': image})

def image_list(request):
    images = Image.objects.all()
    return render(request,'images/image/list.html',{'images':images})
```

As it can be seen, the 'detail' view has 2 arguments : id and slug.
In the template above I get those arguments to the respective picture's id and slug (`id=picture.id slug=picture.slug`).
After I did run the server, when I tried to access the list page on my website,

I got an "NoReverseMatch" error : 
*Exception Value:   Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 1, 'slug': 'django-and-duke'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:[]*.

I started up the shell, imported the Image model, and I wanted to check if there really isn't any image with that id and slug.

```
>>> Image.objects.get(id=1,slug='django-and-duke')
<Image: Django and Duke>
```

So there actually is an Image objects with the requested id and slug ...What is going on?

EDIT : Image model :

```
class Image(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='images_created')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                                    blank=True)

    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name='images_liked',
                                    blank=True)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    objects = models.Manager()  # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager()  # Our custom manager.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('images:detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])`
```

Comment: Which urls.py are those patterns in? If they are not in the main project's urls.py, then how are you including them?

Comment: That error doesn't say that the item doesn't exist, it says it can't find your URL pattern.

Comment: post your model, is there a `get_absolute_url` method defined there?

Comment: Is there a namespace given to your app? Maybe you have to write it like this: `<a href="{% url 'namespace:detail' id=picture.id slug=picture.slug %}">`

Comment: @Alasdair The urls of the images aplication are included in the project's urls : `url(r'^images/', include('images.urls', namespace='images')),`

Comment: @BernardParah posted

Comment: @nik_m Omg. It fking worked. I just changed the code to :'a href="{% url "images:detail" id=picture.id slug=picture.slug %}">' and it loaded and everything ... Can you explain me why thought ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [namespacing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) the url. So, it would be something like that:

```
<a href="{% url 'images:detail' id=picture.id slug=picture.slug %}">
```

In your root `urls.py` you probable have something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include('images.urls', namespace='images'))
]
```

Some edits-thoughts:

1. The `id=` and `slug=` part inside the `{% url %}` are not required. It works without them. But *explicit is better than implicit*, right?
2. When an error of: `Exception Value: Reverse for '<view_name>' with arguments '('arg1', ...)' and keyword arguments '{'key1': kayvalue1, ...}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:[]` occurs, then 99% of the times the `url pattern` found (with correct args or/and kwargs) but a `namespace` is missing. Solution: `{% url 'namespace:view_name' args/kwrags here %}`
3. When an error of: `Exception Value: Reverse for '<view_name>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:[]` occurs, then 99% of the times the `url pattern` found **but args or/and kwargs have not been recognised**. Solution: better check the declaration/syntax of your `urls`